# How to merge .reg file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, registry, process.start

I'm trying to add registry key :

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\TESTKEY")
```

but key is created under :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TESTKEY

same thing happens when I try to merge `.reg` file using `process.start()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you have a 64-bit computer but you're application is running as 32-bit.

64-bit computers will save any key from a 32-bit application to that subkey.

Run your application as 64-bit & a correcy subkey will be made.

Comment: thanks, that helped me a lot. When i target x64 platform everything works ok.